# symfony3 Collection of Forms add array prob

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I want a save An array to the DB like [this tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html).

```
class Itineraire
{

    /**
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */


    private $id ;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Croisiere")
     */

    public $croisiere;




    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",nullable=true)
     */
    private $jour ;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255,nullable=true)
     */

class Croisiere
{

     /**
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */

    private $id ;

    /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Navire",inversedBy="Croisiere")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_navire", referencedColumnName="id")
 */

    public $id_navire;


 /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Itineraire", mappedBy="Croisiere" )
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"id"="ASC"})
     */

    protected $days ;


    formType = 
       ->add('days',CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' =>                    ItineraireType::class,
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                "prototype"=>true,
                "prototype_data"=>new Itineraire()
```

Action

```
public function addCruiseAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) ) {

        return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_security_login');
    }
    $id =  $this->getUser()->getId();

    $croisiere = new Croisiere();
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $ProfileCroisiere = $em->getRepository('GstaycarBundle:ProfileCroisiere')->findOneBy(array('id_user' => $id ));



    $tab = new ArrayCollection();

    // Create an ArrayCollection of the current Tag objects in the database




    /*$day1 = new Itineraire();

    $croisiere->getDays()->add($day1);
    $day2 = new Itineraire();

    $croisiere->getDays()->add($day2);*/


    $form = $this->createForm(CroisiereType::class,$croisiere);


    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() ) {
        if ($form->isValid()){
            var_dump($croisiere);
            $croisiere->setIdProfile($ProfileCroisiere);

            $em->persist($croisiere);

             foreach ($tab as $day) {


            $em->persist( $day);

            }

        //$em->persist( $day2);
        //$em->persist( $day1);
        $em->flush();
        //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('show_ship',array('msg'=>"add successful")));
        }
    }

   **twig** 

      <ul class="days" data-prototype="{{            form_widget(form.days.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        {% for f in form.days %}
            {{ form_widget(f) }}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>

Script Jquery
<script>
  var $collectionHolder;


   // setup an "add a tag" link
    var $addTagLink = $('<button href="#" 
   class="add_tag_link">Add a       tag</button>');
   var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addTagLink);
   var index=0;
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 // Get the ul that holds the collection of days
  $collectionHolder = $('ul.days');

  // add the "add a tag" anchor and li to the days ul
  $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);

    // count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
    // index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
 $collectionHolder.data('index',   $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

    $addTagLink.on('click', function(e) {
  // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
e.preventDefault();

  // add a new tag form (see next code block)
    addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
    });
  });

   function addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
    // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
     var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');

   // get the new index
    var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');

   // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
   var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

   // increase the index with one for the next item
   $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

   // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
  var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
   $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);
  }

  </script>

    <script>
   var $collectionHolder;


   // setup an "add a tag" link
    var $addTagLink = $('<button href="#" 
   class="add_tag_link">Add a       tag</button>');
   var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addTagLink);
   var index=0;
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     // Get the ul that holds the collection of days
      $collectionHolder = $('ul.days');

      // add the "add a tag" anchor and li to the days ul
      $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);

    // count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
    // index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
   $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

    $addTagLink.on('click', function(e) {
    // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
    e.preventDefault();

   // add a new tag form (see next code block)
     addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
   });
   });

   function addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
    // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
    var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');

  // get the new index
  var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');

 // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
 // instead be a number based on how many items we have
 var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

 // increase the index with one for the next item
 $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

 // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
 var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
 $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);
}
```

[this is the view](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)
this is what i want to save in database as an array

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/igvfN.png
```

Comment: Can you please explain in the question what exactly the problem is?

Comment: i want to add multiple days OnetoMany i folow this tuto https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html  but they didnt mention the action of add as an ArrayCollection